# Insert a const wchar_t* into a MySql table

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to insert a serial number into Mysql database like that :

```
wchar_t serial[]=L"34434xxxxx555555";

sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO log (serial_ID,START_DATE) VALUES (%d,now())",serial);

mysql_query(conne, query);
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you even sure the `sprintf` works correctly, given a `%d` format specifier for a wide string? Also, why not simply hard-code the string with the data to ensure the query works instead of introducing `sprintf` into the picture (which may be the reason for the error).  It makes no sense to use `sprintf` if you can't get the query to work using a hard-coded string.  Get that to work first.

Comment: No i'm not sure

Comment: in fact, my application request that the user insert a serial number, so the user insert for example "cxvxvxvxv" then my application verify if the serial entred exist in a tablex , if yes it insert the serial into another table

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from determining what makes the `mysql_query` successful if you just tried your own string first.  For example, `mysql_query(conne, "This is my test");`  Get something like that to work first.  That is what any good programmer would do if they were to get a problem like yours.  Once you know what the string should look like, **then** you fight your battles with `sprintf`, not before.

Comment: do you mean sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO log (serial_ID,START_DATE) VALUES (%d,now())",34434xxxxx555555);

Comment: I think you're under the impression that `sprintf` works like a sql query.  It isn't a query.  The `%d` in sprintf means `int`, and you're supplying a string.  That goes back to my very first comment.  Why not simply output what that `query` looks like before you call `mysql_query`?  Does it look like something that should work?

Comment: it works when i hard-code it

Comment: ok, now you know what output `sprintf` is supposed to produce.  What is it producing now?

Comment: An integer.....

Comment: No, I mean the entire string.  Anyway, realize that `sprintf` works with non-wide strings, so writing a wide string using a function that takes non-wide characters isn't going to work (at least not easily).  The function to use is probably `swprintf`, along with the proper formatting character.  Or better yet, `std::wostringstream` and use `<<` to produce the string.

Comment: thanks a loot for your answers i resolve it using snprintf